# Tensorboard scalar plotting with epoch number on the horizontal axis

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am new to TensorFlow, and I recently started to play around a little bit with data visualization using Tensorboard.
I was wondering if it is possible to convert the horizontal axis of the monitoring scalars (I monitor accuracy and loss on train and validation) to show epoch number instead of iteration number.
the only way I can think of how to do it is to change the sampling frequency to one per epoch, but I am interested in keeping the original sampling resolution.

is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by passing the epoch number to the `global_step` parameter of the `add_summary()` method:

```
summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(log_dir)

my_summary = session.run(my_summary_op, feed_dict)
summary_writer.add_summary(my_summary, global_step=epoch_number)
```

Comment: why do you think it is a good idea? Imagine you have 100 batches and you write summary 100 times during 1 epoch with the same global_step value. I think it will be confusing.
As for me, I would prefer to write each iteration like always, but I'd like to have some vertical lines corresponding to epoch last iteration number on the plot.

Comment: How do you obtain those vertical lines in tensorboard? @RomanS

Comment: I haven't. I just dream to have it ))

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is using [`add_scalars()`](https://tensorboardx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tensorboard.html#tensorboardX.SummaryWriter.add_scalars).

```py
writer = SummaryWriter()
for idx_epoch in range(epochs):
    for idx_batch in range(batches):
        # fetch data
        data, target = None, None
        # compute loss
        loss = nn.L1Loss(data, target)
        # backward propagation

        global_step = idx_epoch*batches+idx_batch
        writer.add_scalars('loss', {'batch':loss}, global_step)
    writer.add_scalars('loss', {'epoch':loss}, global_step)
```

> Note that these codes are actually pseudo codes, which means they cannot run.
>
> Notice that there is a loss writing for every batch as well as every epoch.

Then the tensorboard result will look like this:
[image]

> Red line records the loss every epoch, while blue line records batchly.